# Teleoping a 6dof robot

Tags: drake

I am trying to teleoperate a 6-DOF robot using the sliders provided by the Meshcat interface. A wall is also included in my environment. Finally, I would like to analyze the forces during collision interaction between the robot and wall.

To achieve the teleoperation, the following code takes inspiration from the finger-controlled point [as used here](https://deepnote.com/workspace/Manipulation-ac8201a1-470a-4c77-afd0-2cc45bc229ff/project/87d8044f-3eb2-4f25-b52f-f51a5eca68b7/notebook/point_finger-c961c7f9eeef4aabb2eda47833464013) with the `InverseDynamicsController`:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()

plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.001)
parser = Parser(plant)

parser.AddModels(robotUrdfPath)
parser.AddModels(wallUrdfPath)
plant.mutable_gravity_field().set_gravity_vector(accDueToGravVec)
plant.Finalize()

MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
ContactVisualizer.AddToBuilder(
        builder,
        plant,
        meshcat,
        ContactVisualizerParams(radius=0.005, newtons_per_meter=40.0),
    )

controller_scene_graph = builder.AddSystem(SceneGraph())

controller_plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.005)
controller_plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(controller_scene_graph)
controller_parser = Parser(controller_plant)
controller_parser.AddModels(robotUrdfPath)
controller_plant.Finalize()

controller_vis = MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(
    builder,
    controller_scene_graph,
    meshcat,
    MeshcatVisualizerParams(prefix="controller"),
)
controller_vis.set_name("controller meshcat")

N = controller_plant.num_positions()
kp = [1] * N
ki = [1] * N
kd = [1 * np.sqrt(kp[0])] * N
controller = builder.AddSystem(
    InverseDynamicsController(controller_plant, kp, ki, kd, False)
)
builder.Connect(
    plant.get_state_output_port(),
    controller.get_input_port_estimated_state(),
)

positions_to_state = builder.AddSystem(Multiplexer([N, N]))
zeros = builder.AddSystem(ConstantVectorSource([0] * N))
builder.Connect(zeros.get_output_port(0), positions_to_state.get_input_port(1))
builder.Connect(
    positions_to_state.get_output_port(),
    controller.get_input_port_desired_state(),
)

builder.Connect(
    controller.get_output_port_control(), plant.get_actuation_input_port()
)
positions_to_poses = builder.AddSystem(
    MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose(controller_plant)
)
builder.Connect(
    positions_to_poses.get_output_port(),
    controller_scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(controller_plant.get_source_id()),
)
position_sliders = builder.AddSystem(
    JointSliders(
        meshcat,
        controller_plant,
        step=0.01,
        decrement_keycodes=["q1-", "q2-", "q3-", "q4-", "q5-", "q6-"],
        increment_keycodes=["q1+", "q2+", "q3+", "q4+", "q5+", "q6+"],
    )
)
builder.Connect(
    position_sliders.get_output_port(),
    positions_to_state.get_input_port(0),
)
builder.Connect(
    position_sliders.get_output_port(),
    positions_to_poses.get_input_port(),
)
diagram = builder.Build()
display(SVG(pydot.graph_from_dot_data(diagram.GetGraphvizString(max_depth=2))[0].create_svg()))
simulator = Simulator(diagram)
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
meshcat.AddButton("Stop Simulation", "Escape")
while meshcat.GetButtonClicks("Stop Simulation") < 1:
    simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 1.0)
meshcat.DeleteButton("Stop Simulation")
meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()
```

The simulation runs for a second and then stops with an error saying that control wants to set smaller time step; that there are large derivatives being computed.
It would be great if you could help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The "smaller time step" error means that you have something with continuous-time dynamics in your simulation that is going unstable.  Presumably that is the integrator in the InverseDynamics PID controller.  This is probably a cascade from having the simulation itself go unstable.  I would recommend tuning the PID gains and/or reducing the time step passed to the constructor of the MultibodyPlant.